# How to create a button with a key shortcut label on it?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm writing a Python and PyQt5 program for people who prefer to use the keyboard rather than the mouse (e.g. Emacs users). I think it would be useful for some buttons to display the key shortcut that executes their action, like this:

[image: Mock-up of buttons with key shortcuts written on them]

One way to achieve this seems to be to subclass `QPushButton`, override its `paintEvent` method, use `QPushButton`'s painting and then draw over it with `QPainter.drawRoundedRect` and `QPainter.drawText`. However, I'm new to Qt and have some questions:

1. Is this the best way?
2. To create a "professional" widget, what other methods should I override? `sizeHint`, `minimumSizeHint`, some others?
3. How to draw a `QPushButton` with its text and icon off-center, so that when I paint the key shortcut over it, it'll be the right size and centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A shortcut key can be specified by preceding the preferred character
>   with an ampersand in the text. For example:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("&Download", this);
```

This will use the platform default way to indicate what the shortcut key is.

If you want custom looks and flexibility, it will be best to implement a "complete" or as you call it "professional" widget. In both cases, with QtWidgets you are stuck with doing the painting manually. Also consider whether you want custom or platform native look and feel.

Best solution for custom UI is to move away from the QtWidget stack and use QtQuick2. But I am not sure how usable it is with Python.